# java: tetris random block generated upon row clear

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make the game Tetris in java.

I've gotten it to the point where:

- a new block is generated when it hits the floor or its y+1 is not null (meaning there's another block under it)

  ```
  public void collisionCheck(int x, int y) {
      if (activetile.getY() == this.height-2 || getTileAt(x, y+1) != null) {
          activetile = new Tile(this, 0, 0);    
     }
  }
  ```
- A row clears when the bottom row is full of non-null values, or the Tetris pieces (for y = 4 (the floor), loop through x till x = 4 and check if all non-null)

  ```
  public void checkBottomFull(int x, int y) {
  while (getTileAt(x,y) != null) {    
      say("(" + x + ", " + y +")");
      if (x == 3) {
          say("row is full");     
          //replace full row with tiles from above
          for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
                  grid[j][i] = getTileAt(i,j-1);
                  grid[j-1][i] = null;
              }
          }
      break;
      }       
     x++;
    }
  }
  ```

Right now, I'm using keys to move the block:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        activetile.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1);
        System.out.println("coordinates: " + activetile.getX() + ", " + activetile.getY());

        collisionCheck(activetile.getX(),activetile.getY());

        checkBottomFull(0,4);

        repaint();
    }
  }
```

---

There's two issues I'm having:

1) In the picture you'll notice I've dropped the block all the way to the floor... and the row cleared. After it's cleared, it will generate a block to the top left (x=0, y=1) which I have no control over.

2) On the floor there seems to be a red line... which I'm assuming is a row of blocks hidden by the JFrame... I'm not sure why that's there.

[image]

FYI: If you're wondering why grid[j][i] has the rows and columns flipped (aka, why it's not grid[i][j]) is because I instantiated it as `grid = new Tile[height][width];`

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah,

Turns out in the key event, I needed to check if the bottom was full before checking if there is a collision.

I guess what was happening is, when I was checking `collisionCheck(activetile.getX(),activetile.getY());` before `checkBottomFull(0,4);`, when the bottom was full, it would clear the row and set the current row equal to the row above it: `grid[j][i] = getTileAt(i,j-1);`, the problem was that `collisionCheck` was generating a new piece and the that newly generated piece was getting cleared and replaced by `checkBottomFull`.

Putting the collision check after the `checkBottomFull` ensures that the newly generated piece won't be replaced if bottom is full.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what is wrong without actually debugging your app.
But maybe try this one:

```
public void checkBottomFull(int x, int y) {
    while (getTileAt(x,y) != null) {    
    say("(" + x + ", " + y +")");
    if (x == 3) {
        say("row is full");     
        //replace full row with tiles from above
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
                grid[j][i] = getTileAt(i,j-1);
                grid[j-1][i] = null;
            }
        }
    break;
    }       
   x++;
   }
}
```

You have 5 rows (indexed from 0 to 4) and 4 columns (indexed from 0 to 3).
What values of height and width do you pass to:
    grid = new Tile[height][width];

Because from what I see you should do something like that:
    grid = new Tile[5][4];